# Trouble capturing audio through LMS

Tags: javascript, html

I have some trouble capturing audio through LMS.

When I connect to my webpage to capture audio, the navigator sends a request to access the mic.
But when I connect through an LMS, the navigator does not send the request.

I think is because the LMS is blocking the access to my website resources. But I don't how to unblock the access.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

We have to allow the authorization in the iframe by using this tag

*"allow="microphone"* in the iframe